# How to delete all directories except last 2 directories and the symlink pointed to those directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have below directory structure.

```
~/test_dir$ls -lrt
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  5 kk  Users   160B Apr 17 23:53 app1/
drwxr-xr-x  5 kk  Users   160B Apr 17 23:53 app2/
drwxr-xr-x  5 kk  Users   160B Apr 17 23:53 app3/
drwxr-xr-x  5 kk  Users   160B Apr 17 23:53 app4/
drwxr-xr-x  5 kk  Users   160B Apr 17 23:53 app5/

~/test_dir$cd app1

~/test_dir/app1$ls -rlt
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk  10677    64B Apr 19 14:16 release1/
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk  10677    64B Apr 19 14:16 release2/
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk  10677    64B Apr 19 14:16 release3/
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk  10677    64B Apr 19 14:16 release4/
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk  10677    64B Apr 19 14:17 release5/
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk  10677    64B Apr 19 14:17 relase23/
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk  10677    64B Apr 19 14:17 release8.9/
lrwxr-xr-x  1 kk  10677     8B Apr 19 14:18 Current@ -> release4

~/test_dirls -t1 | tail -n +3 | grep -v Current
relase23/
release5/
release4/
release3/
release2/
release1/
```

How to keep or preserve only the last two directories which are modified recently including the symlinks and their respective directories pointed to them?

I have tried the below

```
~/test_dirls -t1 | tail -n +3 | grep -v Current 
relase23/
release5/
release4/
release3/
release2/
release1/

~/test_dir/app1$ls -t1 | tail -n +3 | grep -v Current | xargs rm -r
~/test_dir/app1$ls -rlt
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk  10677    64B Apr 19 14:17 release8.9/
lrwxr-xr-x  1 kk  10677     8B Apr 19 14:18 Current@ -> release4
```

but that one is even deleting the directories pointing to symlink , keeping only the broken symlink.

```
#!/bin/bash
array=("app1" "app2" "app3" "app4" "app5")

for ((i=0;i<${#array[@]};i++))
do
app=${array[$i]}
echo "the app dir name is: $app"
cd ~/test_dir/$app
count=$(ls -t1 | tail -n +4 | grep -v Current | wc -l)
echo "number of directories deleted are:"
if [ $count == 0 ]
then
echo "Nothing to delete"
echo " "
else
ls -t1 | tail -n +4 | grep -v Current| xargs rm -r
fi
done
exit
```

Expected results are

```
~/test_dir/app1$ls -t1 | tail -n +3 | grep -v Current | xargs rm -r
~/test_dir/app1$ls -rlt
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk  10677    64B Apr 19 14:16 release4/
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk  10677    64B Apr 19 14:17 release8.9/
lrwxr-xr-x  1 kk  10677     8B Apr 19 14:18 Current@ -> release4
```

The release4/ shouldn't get deleted which points to symlink and the symlink too. Any help Thanks.

Comment: Where did that beer icon came from? This code format supports emoticons?

Comment: Please check the existing responses and clarify your requirements.

Comment: echo -e "\xF0\x9f\x8d\xba" will give you the beer icon

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

You want to retain only the two directories last modified.
You do not want to remove symlinks at all.

```
kept=0
stat -c "%Y %n %F" * | sort -rn |
while read timestamp dir type
do [[ directory == "$type" ]] || continue
   ls -ld $dir/ # for logging only 
   if (( kept++ < 2 ))
   then echo "Keeping $dir"
   else echo "Removing $dir"
        rm -fr $dir
   fi
done
```

This will not address symlinks at all, though we could add that if you want it. The same is true for plain files, etc.

...[Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: This is wrong in 2 ways: 1) It does not remove "relase23". 2) It removes "release4".

Comment: 1) This is intentional. It explicitly skips "relase23" as not meeting the naming convention. Easy to remove the `release` from `release*` which will make it apply to all subdirectories if that's preferred. 2) It successfully preserved `release4` in my tests, based on *modification* time. Is anyone else seeing this same fail if after creating all the subdirectories you touch a file in `release4` and `release8.9`?

Comment: 1) "Expected results" as given shows relase23 deleted. 2) release4 is older than 5, 23 and 8.9. Thus it is removed. But even if it would be newer: You code does not reflect the dir Current@ is pointing to.

Comment: Which is why I specified assumptions and results different from the OP, which seemed like a typo. Still waiting for feedback from the requestor on details, which I will refine to spec when spec is clear.

Comment: My directories dont' have common name formats i gave it for example. The directory was a typo relase23/ it should be release23/

Comment: You want to retain only the two directories last modified.
You do not want to remove symlinks at all. Yes

Comment: Ok. I removed `release` from the code. I recommend commenting out the `rm -fr $dir` until you see that it's retaining the ones you want and removing the others. Let me know if you need adjustments.

Comment: BTW - "do not parse stat output" - it could be different depending on LANG or LC_* env vars. ;-) 
$ stat -c "%Y %n %F" * | sort -rn
1555718025 19.02 Verzeichnis
1555676280 Current@ symbolische Verknüpfung
1555676160 release4 Verzeichnis

Comment: You really seem to need for me to be wrong about things.

Answer (score 0):

```
SKIP="$(readlink Current@)";ls -trd release*|grep -v "^$SKIP$"|head -n -1|while read f;do rm -rf rela* "$f";done
```

EDIT 2:

The OP changed the specification slightly: There are also other directories.

```
18.09/ 19.01/ 19.02/ 19.03/ 19.05/ 19.04/
```

I slightly changed the "one liner" to capture also THIS:

```
[user123@matrix app1]$ mkdir 18.09/ 19.01/ 19.02/ 19.03/ 19.05/ 19.04/
[user123@matrix app1]$ ls -ltr
insgesamt 28
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user123 user123 4096 19. Apr 14:16 release4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user123 user123    8 19. Apr 14:18 Current@ -> release4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user123 user123    0 20. Apr 01:45 1
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user123 user123 4096 20. Apr 01:48 19.05
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user123 user123 4096 20. Apr 01:48 19.04
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user123 user123 4096 20. Apr 01:48 19.03
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user123 user123 4096 20. Apr 01:48 19.02
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user123 user123 4096 20. Apr 01:48 19.01
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user123 user123 4096 20. Apr 01:48 18.09
[user123@matrix app1]$ SKIP="$(readlink Current@)";ls -tr|egrep -v "^$SKIP$|^Current@$"|head -n -1|while read f;do rm -rf "$f";done
[user123@matrix app1]$ ls -l
insgesamt 8
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user123 user123 4096 20. Apr 01:48 18.09
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user123 user123    8 19. Apr 14:18 Current@ -> release4
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user123 user123 4096 19. Apr 14:16 release4
[user123@matrix app1]$
```

Comment: Add files to `release4` and `release8.9` and they will have the more recent modification times.

Comment: Adding a file would just set the CURRENT time at the dir. And as you see the directories have the same timestamps as yours. There's no issue about setting the timestamps of the directories for me. But YOUR timestamps only have timestamps up to minute's resolution. Better use something like "date +%s -r release4" if you want to have EXACT prerequisites and answer. Nevertheless: My solution matches your acceptance criteria. :-)

Comment: OP specified "last two directories which are modified recently". I'm using `stat` with %Y which provides Epoch modification timestamps to the second.

Comment: You already mentioned the parsing stuff. Actually the information in the provided document is trivial. And it is generic information. Actually there is no issue about using ls here on the given specification. It offers a "one liner" solution.

Comment: stat with %Y is irrelevant. user8895496 didn't use it. And ls honors also up to second's resolution. Try this: "touch -d '@0' 1;touch -d '@1' 2;touch -d '@0' 3;ls -t ?"

Comment: BTW - sorry for "your acceptance criteria". I mixed you up with user8895496. And it was user8895496 who only "provided" timestamps up to minute's resolution.

Comment: NP. The `read` I used is as broken for embedded spaces. If you just wanted it as a one-liner that skips the symlink and its target, `stat -c "%Y %n" * | sort -rn | sed -En "1,2d; / Current|$(readlink Current)/d; s/^[^ ]+ ([^ ]+).*/\1/; p;" | xargs rm -fr
` ...but I'm still waiting for clarity from the OP.

Comment: This is keeping only the symlink and the directory pointed to it after running it multiple times.`SKIP="$(readlink Current@)";ls -trd release*|grep -v "^$SKIP$"|head -n -2|xargs rm -rf rela*`

Comment: It works with one single run. And with multiple runs I there is nothing more changed. No more release dirs are removed in additional runs. I repeated it several times. If you have this issue then something's wrong at your end (e.g. not Linux or not Bash) or the files/directory structure is not like shown on your question.

Comment: Its not like the directories name is starting with release example, `~/test_dir/app1$ls -trd *|grep -v $(readlink Current) | grep -v Current
 release23/
18.09/
19.01/
19.02/
19.03/
19.05/
19.04/` I want to retain only the two directories last modified. I do not want to remove symlinks at all. Thanks.

Comment: Then the specification in your question is WRONG! You wrote: "I have below directory structure." What you are telling NOW is different. My solution works perfectly for your specification. If the specification is wrong then it is not my fault.